# Summernote set text through passed parameter in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, summernote

My laravel controller passes parameters to the view which I can access by `$note` in `{{ }}`. All right, it works. I can get note's title. However, when I want to set the HTML for summernote, it somehow doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#editor').summernote('code', '{{ $note->html }}');
```

as well as unescaped using `{!! $note->html !!}}`. The result is a summernote editor which looks like a normal text input. **However,** when manually setting `[...]('code', '<html><h1>some html for example</h1></html>)[...]` it works like a charm.

It is obvious that it's related to the way `blade` is putting out data using `{{ }}` but I can't currently figure out why. Using unescaped html had been the first approach that popped up in my mind.

Comment: Take a look at the resulting output and see if there's a `'` in it or something.

Comment: Actually, I was just about to do this. The browser console tells me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, and `$('#editor').summernote('code', '<p>Could not contact K&ouml;rbel Mr.</p>
');`

Comment: I now tried `stripslashes`, still the same

Comment: Mhh.. Is there something suspect with the string I'm trying to display? I can't see it.

Comment: Hmm, I can't either. Try this: `$('#editor').summernote('code', {!! json_encode($note->html) !!});`

Comment: That works. Please submit this as answer so I can check it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When outputting PHP data for JavaScript to use, I like to use `json_encode` on the variable. This guarantees variables get output in a JavaScript-friendly version - it'll wrap strings in `'` marks, leave integers alone, and output complex arrays/objects as proper JSON.

```
$('#editor').summernote('code', {!! json_encode($note->html) !!});
```

Comment: Voted for brief and overlooking explanation of json_encode.